# (Un-)oriented manifold with (un-)oriented interfaces

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, geometric-topology, surgery-theory

Are there examples that

1. An un-oriented manifold is glued from pieces of oriented manifolds [with boundaries], separated by interfaces [where boundaries are glued]? I suppose a Mobius strip is one example, but do we have any concrete 4-dimensional **example** [glued from 3-dimensional interfaces] and 3-dimensional manifold examples [glued from 2-dimensional interfaces]?
2. An un-oriented **closed** manifold is glued from pieces of oriented manifolds [with boundaries], separated by interfaces [where boundaries are glued]? Do we have any concrete 4-dimensional manifold **examples** [glued from 3-dimensional interfaces] and 3-dimensional manifold examples [glued from 2-dimensional interfaces]?
3. An oriented **closed** manifold is glued from pieces of un-oriented manifolds [with boundaries], separated by interfaces [where boundaries are glued]?

Please give examples. Are interfaces oriented or unoriented in these cases?
Thanks a lot.